# Trigonometry(Compound Angles)

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that:-
$$\tan 2 \theta+\tan 3 \theta -\tan5\theta=-\tan 2\theta.\tan3\theta.\tan5\theta$$

I cannot figure out how to start solving this problem......

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem if you use $$\tan (x+y) = {\tan x+ \tan y \over 1-\tan x\cdot \tan y}$$

Comment: I know that too but when and where to use it?

Comment: Use $2 \theta+3 \theta=5\theta$

Comment: I did it in this way:- $$tan2\theta+tan3 \theta-tan(2\theta+3\theta)$$ This evaluated to $$tan(2\theta+3\theta)-tan2\theta-tan3\theta$$ Now what?

Comment: You didn't use formula

Comment: Ok I solved it. Figured out the mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

lhs:

$tan2\theta+tan3\theta-tan5\theta$

using the formula with $x=2\theta$ and $y=3\theta$

($tan5\theta$)($1-tan2\theta tan3\theta)$ - $tan5\theta$

multiplying out gives

$tan5\theta-tan2\theta tan3\theta tan5\theta-tan5\theta$

equals the rhs

so the question should read

$tan2\theta+tan3\theta-tan5\theta = -tan2\theta tan3\theta tan5\theta$

Comment: Looks like you missed a 2 in your question .... I'll edit it for you ... could be why you were stuck in the first place

Comment: Should really be an equivalent symbol not an equals sign too